# how to check device brand name at installation time

Tags: android, installation

how to check device brand name at installation time of app in android.
i want to do cancel installation  when brand does not match.

code for get brand name-
String brand = android.os.Build.BRAND;

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cancel installation, nor you can't execute anything before you are installed (which shall be rather obvious) and launched manually by the user at least once.

If you want to limit access to your application to device matching certain characteristics, read this article: [Filters on Google Play](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/filters.html)

Comment: That's strange. However, you can limit which devices that it can install to if this is getting downloaded from Google Play

Comment: That's not strange. That's pretty sane. If any code would be executed without user control, imagine what malware or other crap would be doing